# How to bundle external CMake dependencies to generate a Python package?

Tags: python, cmake, pybind11, python-bindings

I am trying to generate Python bindings for the [OpenVSlam](https://github.com/xdspacelab/openvslam) project.

I am using PyBind11 and following the [cmake_example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example) template.

I successfully build the `.so` file using `pybind11_add_module` in my development environment, in which I have all dependencies installed (libraries such as OpenCV, Protobuf, etc...). The `.so` file works well in this development environment. I can run `import sys; sys.path.append('.'); import openvslam_python;` and use the binding functions properly. However, I would like to ship the `.so` file as a Python package.

The problem is that when I run `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` and try to install the resulting `wheel` on another environment (without the installed dependencies) it says it cannot find the dependencies' `.so` files. For example, it outputs the following error (in a Docker container):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('.')
>>> import openvslam_python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libopenvslam.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I would like to know if there is a way of bundling the dependencies of the PyBind11 bindings with CMake (or maybe inside the `setup.py` script) to be able to install them in environments that do not have any of the dependencies installed. This way, I could install the bindings anywhere with a simple `pip install` command.